# Running a web service without authorization

Tags: asp.net, ajax, web-services

I have an application that uses forms authentication. However there are some web service calls that I want to be able to run from a Jquery Ajax call even if the user is not logged in. At the moment running these web services causes a 401 Unauthorized error. Is there some way I can allow certain web services to be run without authorisation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, simply adding this in the web.config file did the trick

```
<location path="myWebService.asmx">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
   <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```